# How do I unwind a map in neo4j and access the keys and values

Tags: neo4j

I have a map<string, string> parameter that I pass into my cypher.

How do I access the key and values?

```
unwind $map as keyValue
match (n:ANode {name:keyValue.Key})
match (n2:ANode {name:keyValue.Value})
merge (n)-[:aRelation]->(n2)
```

This throws no error, but no relation is created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need use APOC function and sort the properties of the map. You can simply access the keys using keys(map) then use the key to g)et the values like map[key]

For example:

```
WITH {name:"Cristiano Ronaldo",country:"Portugal",dob:date("1985-02-05")} AS map
UNWIND keys(map) as key 
RETURN key, map[key] as value
```

Result:

```
╒═════════╤═══════════════════╕
│"key"    │"value"            │
╞═════════╪═══════════════════╡
│"country"│"Portugal"         │
├─────────┼───────────────────┤
│"dob"    │"1985-02-05"       │
├─────────┼───────────────────┤
│"name"   │"Cristiano Ronaldo"│
└─────────┴───────────────────┘
```

Comment: This seems like the better solution